Aiogram: Ошибка TelegramRetryAfter при использовании EditMessageMedia
Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать игру "морской бой" в телеграмме. После выстрелов бота редактирую картинку-поле с помощью:
photo = InputMediaPhoto(media=FSInputFile(f'player_fields/{callback.from_user.id}.jpg'), caption=caption)
await callback.message.edit_media(media=photo, reply_markup=get_field_keyboard(callback.from_user.id))

Всё работает прекрасно. Решил вместо картинки выводить анимацию серии выстрелов:
animation=InputMediaAnimation(media=FSInputFile(f'player_animations/{callback.from_user.id}.gif'), caption=caption)                                                                     
await callback.message.edit_media(media=animation, reply_markup=get_field_keyboard(callback.from_user.id))

Сперва все работает нормально, но через несколько ходов бота и соответственно замен анимации возникает ошибка:
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramRetryAfter: Telegram server says - Flood control exceeded on method 'EditMessageMedia' in chat 5845612506. Retry in 243 seconds.Original description: Too Many Requests: retry after 243

Сперва решил, что проблема в слишком большом размере анимации. Снижение разрешения анимации не помогло. Размер картинок почти вдвое больше размера анимации, но при их изменении ошибок не возникало. Также пробовал делать задержку перед изменением анимации вплоть до 5 сек, также не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

Нет, просто телега говорит что вы спамите серваки телеграма попытками поменять содержимое сообщения EditMessageMedia. Короче проще будет отказаться от анимации
